# How to stop cat from pooping on carpet?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

We have owned a cat for about 9 years, who has always used his litter box. We recently had a bunny for a short time and when we let it out, the bunny pooped in our living room in some of the corners. The bunny is no longer here but now the cat keeps pooping in the same spot the bunny did. How can we stop the cat from pooping in this same spot?

Comment: remove carpet maybe.

Answer (score 2):

When a cat breaks litter box protocol -- unless it was unable to get to the box, e.g. by a door being closed or another cat deciding to guard it -- this is usually an indication of illness and time for a vet visit.

After that, treat the marked area with an enzyme-based cleaner (available from pet stores under multiple brand names) to remove all traces of the scent, which might otherwise encourage a repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for such a behaviour might be stress. Maybe something changed? Other animals / people which trouble your cat? And please consider that cats have other standards than humans have so it might be something simple like this: I know a cat which was avoiding its litter box after a balloon burst near it.

If your cat does not have a health problem and you cannot find another reason - maybe you could to train her. E. g. put a litter box at the place your cat is using now and pull it back to the original place step by step - a short distance each day.

Answer (score 0):

> We recently had a bunny for a short time and when we let it out, the
>   bunny pooped in our living room in some of the corners. The bunny is
>   no longer here but now the cat keeps pooping in the same spot the
>   bunny did.

Cats are very much into smells, and are known to urinate or poop on places that smell like urine\poop from before.
I'm thinking your cat is pooping on those places because it can still smell that there has been poop there before.
I would've tried spraying anti-cat fumes on those places.

Several fumes/smells can be used to make a cat stay away from certain spots. Most cats hate citrus fruits, pepper, typical human perfumes, tooth paste, and certain products that can be bought in pet stores for this purpose (I don't remember what they are called).